# У меня в кладовой есть всё, что вкусное, — тыква, бкокколи, брюссельская, морковь(,) — всё вкусное

Tags: запятые

Здесь запятая, как я знаю, не нужна.

> У меня в кладовой есть всё, что вкусное: тыква, брокколи, брюссельская, морковь — всё вкусное.

А здесь?

> У меня в кладовой есть всё, что вкусное, — тыква, брокколи, брюссельская, морковь(,) — всё вкусное.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ответ восстановил, случайно часть рассуждений в процессе удалил.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*У меня в кладовой есть всё, что вкусное, — // **тыква, брокколи, брюссельская, морковь — всё вкусное.***

**Решение методом блоков**

**Три предикативные** основы: СПП + простое предложение с однородным рядом.  Граница блоков перед однородным рядом простого предложения.

Отношения между блоками **присоединительные**, обозначаем **единым** знаком.

Answer (score 1):

Давайте сделаем анализ предложения.

**Во-первых**, однородный ряд относится к придаточному, поэтому не отделяется от него запятой:

*У меня в кладовой есть всё, что вкусное — тыква, брокколи, брюссельская, морковь (?) всё вкусное*.

Знаки пока ставить не будем.

**Во-вторых**, по [«Розенталю», пункт 9,](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=103) повторяющиеся обобщающие слова не разделяются запятой. Но у нас случай другой: слово *всë* из главной части, а *вкусное* — из придаточной. Но как тогда понять, ставить запятую или нет — относится второе обобщающее к придаточной или к главной части?

А мой ответ такой: запятая стоять должна:

*У меня в кладовой есть всё, что вкусное — тыква, брокколи, брюссельская, морковь, — всё вкусное*.

Почему — сейчас объясню.

Повторенное обобщающее слово относится именно к главной части. Слово *всë* — обобщающее, а после однородного ряда оно повторяется, но в другом виде — *всë вкусное*. То есть главная часть — неполная:

*У меня в кладовой есть всё [вкусное], что вкусное...*

Таким образом, и однородный ряд нужно отнести к главной части, то есть отделить от придаточной, то есть получаем ваш вариант:

*У меня в кладовой есть всё, **что вкусное**, — тыква, брокколи, брюссельская, морковь — всё вкусное*.

Придаточная часть легко удаляется, поэтому еë нужно обособить, а главная часть является неполной. Тогда запятая перед тире удаляется, мы же придаточное обособили, исключив из него однородный ряд. Давайте посмотрим на предложение без придаточного:

*У меня в кладовой есть всё [вкусное] — тыква, брокколи, брюссельская, морковь — всё вкусное*.

Обобщающие слова, если повторяются перед и после однородного ряда, запятой не разделяются (ссылка уже дана). Следовательно, и с придаточной запятая не нужна:

***У меня в кладовой есть всё, что вкусное, — тыква, брокколи, брюссельская, морковь — всё вкусное***;

***У меня в кладовой есть всё, что вкусное: тыква, брокколи, брюссельская, морковь — всё вкусное*** — запятая, закрывающая придаточное, поглощается двоеточием.

---

Долго мне рассуждать над этим пришлось, но всë-таки я пришëл и привëл вас к лучшим вариантам.

Comment: Мне первый вариант и второй не нравятся. Мне кажется, надо так: *У меня в кладовой есть всё, что вкусное, — тыква, брокколи, брюссельская, морковь, — всё вкусное.* Посмотрите на пример про разговоры из 7-го пункта наверху.

Comment: Фото из какого сайта? Параграф какой?

Comment: @Леопольд-мэтр А, Леопольд, я понял, почему там запятая! Там стоит определительный оборот _полные покорности и злобы_, находящийся в постпозиции и имеющий опредделяемое слово, поэтому и обособлен, — следовательно, запятая закрывает определительный оборот перед тире! Поняли теперь?

Comment: @Леопольд-мэтр А в вашем примере нет перед тире оьособленных оборотов — следовательно, нечему обособляться — следовательно, запятую перед тире ставить нельзя, т. к. просто нет оснований это делать.